# PixiJS: How to use its ResizePlugin

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

At https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.Application.html#queueResize, the PixiJS API documents a `queueResize()` function, but when I try to use it in my browser application I get the following error:

```
TypeError: app.queueResize is not a function
```

Here's a typical example:

```js
let pixi_container = document.getElementById("pixi_container");

app = new PIXI.Application(
    {
        backgroundColor: 0xAAAAAA,
        resizeTo: pixi_container
    }
);

pixi_container.appendChild(app.view);

app.queueResize();  // <-- error here
```

I'm using the latest PixiJS release (as of today).

Is there something I need to do before calling the `queueResize()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Method is undefined because it comes in plugin ( https://pixijs.download/dev/docs/packages_app_src_ResizePlugin.js.html#line36 ) - and probably you didnt registered this plugin yet.

You need to register ResizePlugin and then this method should work. See for example: https://medium.com/@bigtimebuddy/new-pixijs-v5-plugins-75a7d86afb6